# How to do a running sum in python?

Tags: python, list, cumulative-sum

I have a list `Student` which has following structure:

```
[('abc', 50000), ('def', 34000),....]
```

Here the first element of each tuple is a employee ID and second part is the salary. Now what I want to do is first form different buckets based on number of employees. So the buckets will have - `0-5 employees`, `0-10 employees`,`0-15 employees` and so on. For example if I have say 32 employees data in my list then my bucket will be -  `0-5 employees`, `0-10 employees`,`0-15 employees`,`0-20 employees`, `0-25 employees`,`0-30 employees` and finally `0-32 employees`. And with each bucket will be the associated sum of their salaries. Notice that number of employees may vary and also they need not be in perfect combination of 5 employees. But I want them to be in bucketed in buckets 5 employee difference until the end bucket which may have difference of less than 5.

I have tried this so far:

```
count = 0
increment = 5
total_employees = 5
run_salary = 0
emp_bucket = []
for items in List1:
    count += 1
    if count <= total_employees:
        run_salary += items[1]
    else:
        emp_bucket.append(run_salary)
        total_employees += increment
        count = 0
        run_salary = 0
```

I know this code is not correct because when the things got re-initialized the process should start all the way from 1st employees again and not the next employee in the list. My current code starts from the next employee.
What I am having is a hard time in framing this type of bucket with cumulative or running information. How can I form these buckets?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @mguijarr I have added my tried code so far but it is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> data = [('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291), ('vbTxW', 4740), ('rzcRq', 3259), ('ZAJpv', 3800), ('IVGDY', 1499), ('fvCDx', 4432), ('btuUD', 3844), ('fWJUi', 3973), ('nptHC', 4854), ('dbAxH', 1467), ('egeDs', 4514), ('ArvtJ', 4798), ('PGtEh', 1924), ('VkrIb', 1637), ('dbIpm', 1612), ('HShOu', 2425), ('cWZOG', 4286), ('cMESU', 3374), ('fcBpX', 3926), ('VWhFW', 4546), ('FLLmu', 2609), ('XrLEf', 3829), ('xaWZh', 1543)]
>>> 
>>> for group in [data[:i+5] for i in range(0, len(data), 5)]:
...     print group
...     print sum(x[1] for x in group)
...
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051)]
14561
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291)]
33388
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291), ('vbTxW', 4740), ('rzcRq', 3259), ('ZAJpv', 3800), ('IVGDY', 1499), ('fvCDx', 4432)]
51118
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291), ('vbTxW', 4740), ('rzcRq', 3259), ('ZAJpv', 3800), ('IVGDY', 1499), ('fvCDx', 4432), ('btuUD', 3844), ('fWJUi', 3973), ('nptHC', 4854), ('dbAxH', 1467), ('egeDs', 4514)]
69770
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291), ('vbTxW', 4740), ('rzcRq', 3259), ('ZAJpv', 3800), ('IVGDY', 1499), ('fvCDx', 4432), ('btuUD', 3844), ('fWJUi', 3973), ('nptHC', 4854), ('dbAxH', 1467), ('egeDs', 4514), ('ArvtJ', 4798), ('PGtEh', 1924), ('VkrIb', 1637), ('dbIpm', 1612), ('HShOu', 2425)]
82166
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291), ('vbTxW', 4740), ('rzcRq', 3259), ('ZAJpv', 3800), ('IVGDY', 1499), ('fvCDx', 4432), ('btuUD', 3844), ('fWJUi', 3973), ('nptHC', 4854), ('dbAxH', 1467), ('egeDs', 4514), ('ArvtJ', 4798), ('PGtEh', 1924), ('VkrIb', 1637), ('dbIpm', 1612), ('HShOu', 2425), ('cWZOG', 4286), ('cMESU', 3374), ('fcBpX', 3926), ('VWhFW', 4546), ('FLLmu', 2609)]
100907
[('KgqZe', 4675), ('bFbad', 1279), ('oswIx', 2644), ('mEPlC', 2912), ('rnQGs', 3051), ('BTYHr', 3367), ('AgEqM', 2804), ('ovgNh', 4548), ('AlTAn', 4817), ('vOYtV', 3291), ('vbTxW', 4740), ('rzcRq', 3259), ('ZAJpv', 3800), ('IVGDY', 1499), ('fvCDx', 4432), ('btuUD', 3844), ('fWJUi', 3973), ('nptHC', 4854), ('dbAxH', 1467), ('egeDs', 4514), ('ArvtJ', 4798), ('PGtEh', 1924), ('VkrIb', 1637), ('dbIpm', 1612), ('HShOu', 2425), ('cWZOG', 4286), ('cMESU', 3374), ('fcBpX', 3926), ('VWhFW', 4546), ('FLLmu', 2609), ('XrLEf', 3829), ('xaWZh', 1543)]
106279
```

This groups the data into increasing chunks of 5, and prints the group plus the sum of all their salaries.

(Note: I used the `random` library to generate the data, hence why it looks so weird)

*EDIT*

To print the range instead, just change the print statement:

```
>>> for group in [data[:i+5] for i in range(0, len(data), 5)]:
...    print 'Group from 0 to', len(group)
...    print 'Sum:', sum(x[1] for x in group)
...
Group from 0 to 5
Sum: 14561
Group from 0 to 10
Sum: 33388
Group from 0 to 15
Sum: 51118
Group from 0 to 20
Sum: 69770
Group from 0 to 25
Sum: 82166
Group from 0 to 30
Sum: 100907
Group from 0 to 32
Sum: 106279
```

Comment: is it possible that instead of printing the group I can print the range of number of employees like 0-5 employees, 0-10 employees, 0-15 employees and so on?

Comment: See my edit for how to do that - you can do what you like in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ben's answer:

```
 # function to sum a list of (string, int) tuples
 fsum = lambda x: sum(i[1] for i in x)

 buckets = [fsum(salaries[:i]) for i in range(5, len(salaries), 5)]
```